# natural bouncing dice opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to make a bouncing dice in opengl. Going by the principle of "fake it till you make it", I decided to take the equation of an underdamped oscillator and apply that to glTranslate() before running the dice drawing code. Right now, my code looks something like this:-

```
glPushMatrix();
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    diceHeight=10*abs(exp(-0.01*glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME)/100)* cos(glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME)/500));
    cout<<diceHeight;
    glTranslatef(-30, diceHeight, 0);
    object2.draw();
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glPopMatrix();
```

My dice bounce, however, looks completely unnatural. Is there anyway to improve this further?
I really REALLY don't want to go into dice physics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing with your implicit function idea...

```
height(t) = (1 - pow(fract(pow(16, (t+0.25) * 0.6)) * 2 - 1, 2)) * 4 / pow(4, floor(pow(16, (t+0.25) * 0.6)))
```

This uses a fractional component (`fract(x) = x - floor(x)`) to perform a quadratic bounce, which is scaled down each time with a floor component.

Personally, I'd go with the explicit integration, keeping velocity and position variables as @lechariotdor linked.

[image]

Comment: What's fract? Fractional part?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it looks unatural because the dice moves at constant speed. You need to integrate some acceleration factor somewhere. Look at basic euler integration for simple physics [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15708/how-can-i-implement-gravity), it's really easy to implement.

Comment: Hey there! I tried your answer, but the motion is pretty jaggy(probably because I loaded a lot of objects). For the benefit of the others, could you explain how to do this in a frame independent way?

Comment: What do you mean by 'frame independant way' ? With a fixed constant time step ?

Comment: Yeah. Basically something that would perform equally well irrespective of hardware.

Comment: Using a fixed time step would not make it perform well on different kinds of hardware. Faster hardware will run faster, and slower hardware will run it slower (or you need to set a low framerate limit that the slowest hardware can match). To make it run well on different hardwares, you need to calculate the time difference between 2 frames, and use this delta to update your dice position. Making it time dependent would make it run consistently accross different types of hardware. A fixed time step is only useful if you need to predict each step precisely (for replay purposes, networking, ...)

Answer (score 0):

So, I decided to go my own route, make a spline and move the dice along that. Though @jozxyk's answer is the most appropriate

```
//dice code
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
vector3f start=vector3f(-150, 100, 10);
vector3f end=vector3f(-10,10,0);
vector3f perpBisectorDirection=vector3f((start.x+end.x),(start.y+end.y),(start.z+end.z));
vector3f tan1(-(start.x-8*perpBisectorDirection.x+end.x)/6,-(start.y-8*perpBisectorDirection.y+end.y)/6, -(start.z-8*perpBisectorDirection.z+end.z)/6);

glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glLineWidth(12.0);
int t=360;
if (i<=t)
{
    diceRotate++;
    i++;

}
float pos = (float) i / (float) t;

GLfloat x=bezierCurve(pos, start.x, tan1.x, tan1.x,end.x);
GLfloat y=bezierCurve(pos, start.y, tan1.y, tan1.y,end.y);
GLfloat z=bezierCurve(pos, start.z, tan1.z, tan1.z,end.z);
cout<<i;
glTranslatef(x, y, z);

glRotatef(diceRotate, 1, 1, 1);
object2.draw();

glPopMatrix();
```